# ImportError: cannot import name 'BeautifulSoup'

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Why am I getting `ImportError: cannot import name 'BeautifulSoup'`

```
  line 1, in <module>
        from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    ImportError: cannot import name 'BeautifulSoup'
```

Is it installed?

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall beautifulsoup4
Collecting beautifulsoup4
  Using cached beautifulsoup4-4.6.0-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: beautifulsoup4
  Found existing installation: beautifulsoup4 4.6.0
    Uninstalling beautifulsoup4-4.6.0:
      Successfully uninstalled beautifulsoup4-4.6.0
Successfully installed beautifulsoup4-4.6.0
```

Appears so.

Comment: After you installed beautifulsoup4, did you try exiting the terminal and then coming back in.

Comment: Did you name your file `bs4.py` by chance? Try renaming it.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Yeap.  I just deleted that now, moral of the story, do not ever name a python file bs4.py.

Comment: You should mark you question as answered by clicking the green tick below burhan khalid's answer.

Answer (score 5):

Don't name your file `bs4.py`

---

Python has a list of places it will check for modules, from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path):

> When a module named `spam` is imported, the interpreter first searches
>   for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches
>   for a file named `spam.py` in a list of directories given by the
>   variable `sys.path`. `sys.path` is initialized from these locations:
>
> - the directory containing the input script (or the current directory).
> - `PYTHONPATH` (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable `PATH`).
> - the installation-dependent default.

In your case, it found a file called `bs4.py` in the same directory where it was being executed, and since it matches what you are trying to import - Python stopped searching the rest of the directories.

As your own `bs4.py` does not contain the object `BeautifulSoup`, you get the import error.

This sort of name clashing can be avoided by careful naming of your files; it does come in useful in some cases (for example when you are trying to mock or override some modules); but that is not the case here.